# Cakephp pagination of more than one unrelated database table

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to paginate two database tables having same structure(eg SMS and MMS) which are not   related to each other. I want to retrieve records from both the table with some condition (eg records having same date) . suppose there are (5 SMS and 10 MMS) as a result set. How will i paginate both tables and display it in a single instance using cakephp paginate function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest why don't you use `single table for both` if they are having same table structure. And with the help of flag or something you can differentiate `SMS` & `MMS`?

By this cakephp `automatically` handle all default functionality (like pagination , sorting etc..) & it will be easier for you.

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: There are huge number of data in lakhs and the table are designed previously.so i have to use both of them.

Comment: So in that case you have to make custom pagination function modifying the existing one refrence -> http://book.cakephp.org/view/1237/Custom-Query-Pagination